# how to create nested list with for loop in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I'm trying to create a nested list with a for loop

Why its not working and what is the right way to do this?

```
from random import randint

def func1(my_list):
    for i in range(10):
            ans[i][0] = randint(0, len(my_list) - 1) # row
            ans[i][1] = randint(0, len(my_list[0] - 1) # col
    return ans
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What is the "this" that you're trying to do? Try clearly explaining what you want your function to do and what difficulty you're having.

Comment: Does this even work as is? `ans` doesn't exist when accessed, so it should throw an immediate error on `ans[i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what `my_list` looked like in order to get `len(my_list[0] - 1)` to return something useful, but this looks like what you are asking for.

```
from random import randint
ans = [[randint(0, 6), randint(0, 4)] for i in range(5)]
print ans
# [[0, 1], [5, 0], [1, 0], [2, 2], [5, 1]]
```

Comment: really amazing technique!! Thanks. and sorry for not being clear but you got it anyway..